# Why can't I get info window pop up in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a sample info page that has people listed in accordion fashion. What I want to happen is when you click on the "Get Info" button a window pops out and shows more info about the person. I have pop-up blocking disabled. 
Not sure why it won't work. My code is as follows:

> **javascript / jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#holder').hide();
    $('#get-employees').fadeIn();
    $('#get-employees').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('#loader').fadeIn(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.mccinfo.net/epsample/employees"
            }).done(onAjaxComplete);
        });

    });

    function onAjaxComplete(data) {
        var employees = $.parseJSON(data);
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            s += "<h3>" + employees[i].first_name + "" + employees[i].last_name + "</h3>";
            s += "<div id='" + employees[i].id + "'>
            ";
            s += "<p>First Name: " + employees[i].first_name + "</p>";
            s += "<p>Last Name: " + employees[i].last_name + "</p>";
            s += "<p> Image:</p>"
            s += "<img src='" + employees[i].image_filename + "' alt='Image' />";
            s += "<br /></br>";
            s += "<button id='" + employees[i].id + " " + "class='get-info'>Get Info</button>";
            s += "</div>";
            /*
    if( i != employees.length - 1){
    s += "<hr />";
    }
    */
            $("#holder").html(s);
            $("#loader").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#holder").accordion({
                    heightStyle: "content"
                });
                $("#holder").fadeIn();
            });

            $('.get-info').click(function (evt) {
                console.log(this.id);
                evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://www.mccinfo.net/epsample/employees/" + this.id
                }).done(showEmployeeInfo);
            });

        }
    }

    function showEmployeeInfo(data) {
        var employee = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(employee);
        var name = employee.first_name + " " + employee.last_name;
        var salary = accounting.formatMoney(employee.annual_salary);
        $('#dialog').attr('title', name);
        var s = "";
        s += "<p>Image:</p>";
        s += "<img src='" + employee.image_filename + " ' alt='Image' />";
        s += "<p>Hire Date: " + employee.hire_date + "</p>";
        s += "<p>Salary: " + salary + " </p>";
        s += "<p>Department: " + employee.department.name + " </p>";
        $('#dialog').html(s);
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    }
});
```

> **HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ILC 5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/accounting.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="get-employees" class="centered">Click Me to Get Employees</button>
    <div id="loader" style="display:none;" class="centered"><image src="img/image.gif"></div>
    <div id="holder"></div>
    <div id="dialog" title=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any insight on what needs to happen would be appreciated.

Comment: you use bootstrap.css and show person detail in Modal